# Full Screen Video on Extended Desktop

Tags: windows-7, flash-player, external-display

I am running into a problem getting full screen video to play on my extended desktop (TV connected via netgear push2tv using Intel wireless display technology.)  Every time I set a video to play in full screen mode on the TV and then go back to surf the web on the primary monitor it takes the video out of full screen mode as soon as you click anywhere.

The only instance where this does not happen is using netflix streaming instantly using Microsoft Silverlight video player (there was an option in setup to keep video in fullscreen on the secondary display regardless of what is done on the primary monitor)  Is there a similar setting in Flash player, is this a setting I can enable in the control panel?  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This is the typical behaviour of Flash, and most other full screen apps.  As far as I know, there's no way to get it to do what you want.

BTW, it would be a lot clearer if you had said you watching flash videos to begin with.

**UPADATE** Adobe recently released Flash 10.2 (at least for Windows), which supports multi-monitor fullscreen.  I've had a chance to try it out, and it works well, with caveats.  In Firefox, if you put a video into fullscreen, switch back to the browser, and then switch to another tab, the video's frame-rate drops.

Answer (score 0):

I read about a modification for the flash plugin a while back that addresses some of this:

http://lifehacker.com/5419028/keep-flash-videos-in-full-screen-on-dual-monitors

http://lifehacker.com/5560912/keep-flash-101-in-full-screen-on-a-second-monitor

Comment: Just remember, tooling around in a binary file is dangerous at best.  If you try this, make sure that you backup the files first so that if Something Bad(TM) happens, you can get your old functionality back.